# ¿Como puede permitir que cada usuario edite su perfil, uso Laravel, y un generado llamado InfyOm?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web, crud

Buenas soy nuevo en esto, estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema con el framework de PHP Laravel, para empezar cree un CRUD de una tabla que tengo en una base de datos de MySQL con el generador de InfyOm (Aquí pueden verlo y descargarlo http://labs.infyom.com), cualquiera puede registrase y operar dicho CRUD

Lo que yo quiero hacer ahora es que en una pestaña que diga "Perfil" los usuarios puedan editar su información que colocaron al registrarse, si hago un CRUD de la tabla usuarios, todos los usuarios podrán editar la información de cualquier usuario, alguien me puede ayudar, por favor.

Comment: Para que los usuarios no puedan ver ni editar https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#policy-methods

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una ruta que te cargue una una función parecida al **edit()** pero que no recibe ningún parámetro, sino que obtienes el id del usuario por medio de la variable de sesión **Auth::User()->id**, con esto cargas los datos del usuario logueado y lo envías a un formulario para que puedan ser editados por el usuario. Luego para enviar los datos haces algo similar a la ruta anterior donde crees una ruta a una función **update()** que no recibe parámetros y obtienes el id del usuario de la mismas como mencionaba antes y ya simplemente actualizas los datos del usuario.

**Ejemplo**

***rutas***

```
Route::get('perfil/actualizar',['as'=> 'perfil.edit', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@edit']);
Route::patch('perfil/actualizar',['as'=> 'perfil.update', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@update']);
```

***controlador usando InfyOm***

```
public function edit(){
   $usuario = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail(Auth::User()->id);
   if(empty($usuario)){
      Flash::error('mensaje error');
      return redirect()->back();
   }
   return view('editar_perfil')->with('usuario', $usuario);
}

public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request){
   $usuario = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail(Auth::User()->id);
   if(empty($usuario)){
      Flash::error('mensaje error');
      return redirect()->back();
   }
   $input=$request->all();
   $usuario = $this->userRepository->update($input,Auth::User()->id);
   Flash::success('Perfil actualizado con éxito.');
   return redirect(route('index'));
}
```

***controlador sin usar InfyOm***

```
    public function edit(){
       $usuario = User::find(Auth::User()->id);
       if(empty($usuario)){
          Flash::error('mensaje error');
          return redirect()->back();
       }
       return view('editar_perfil')->with('usuario', $usuario);
    }

   public function update(Request $request){
       $usuario = User::find(Auth::User()->id);
       if(empty($usuario)){
          Flash::error('mensaje error');
          return redirect()->back();
       }
       $usuario->fill($request->all());
       $usuario->save();
       Flash::success('Perfil actualizado con éxito.');
       return redirect(route('index'));
    }
```

***vista***

```
<form action="{{route('perfil.update')}}" method="PATCH">
 /** lo que vaya aqui **/
</form>
```

Así te evitas crear todo un crud para solo actualizar el prfil de los usuari, y si quieres adicionar una vista **show()**, solo haces algo similar al **edit()**

DE todas formas si quieres usar los comandos de InfyOm para atajar algun paso puedes usar este **`php artisan infyom:scaffold $MODEL_NAME --views=index,create,edit,show`**

En donde usas **--views=** para especificar las vistas que quieres generar.

Aquí encuentras más información: http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.2/generator-options